# How to pass MyClass.class as a Parameter in my Method?

Tags: java, class, parameters

I'm struggling to use an element as parameter in my code.

For my Hibernate API calls I need to specify which class the query result has to me mapped. Instead of making many small methods which are fairly simmilar I want to DRY it out.

I've got this code here:

```
private void selectAllFrom(MyClass myclass) {
    CriteriaQuery<MyClass> query = builder.createQuery(Myclass.class);
}
```

Instead I want to have the MyClass-Class as a generic parameter and use the method like this:

```
private void selectAllFrom(Class<T> any) {
    CriteriaQuery<Class<T>> query = builder.createQuery(Class<T>.class)
}

// usage: 
// selectAllFrom(MyClass.class)
```

How can this be done in Java?

Comment: I think swapping `CriteriaQuery<any>` for `CriteriaQuery<T>` should do the trick

Comment: `CriteriaQuery<any> query = builder.createQuery(any.class)` -> `CriteriaQuery<T> query = builder.createQuery(any)`

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how `Class<T>` works. The class of `Class<T>` would be `Class<Class<T>>`.

Comment: I'm sorry for this stupid question. Thanks for the great help anyway, would not have been able continue my work without you guys :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work. Note that you must use `T` when referencing a type, and `any` when referencing the `Class<?>` value required by `createQuery` and other methods.

```
private <T> void selectAllFrom(Class<T> any) {
    CriteriaQuery<T> query = builder.createQuery(any)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I cannot use it like this: `selectAllFrom(MyClass.class)`

Comment: Why not? Please add stack trace to the question

Comment: Becuase it is marked red by IntelliJ and why does it return T, I don't need no return type

Comment: @Miger There is no return type here. It's a generic type parameter.

Comment: ok it works now. I left out the <T> because I first thougt it was a return type but then I saw that it is still void, didn't see it before, thanks!